# facebook javascript sdk get extra permissions with omniauth-facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, permissions, facebook-javascript-sdk, omniauth

I'm working on omniauth-facebook with fb js sdk. It works pretty good for right now, however I do not know why it cannot request extra permissions. I already set in my omniauth.rb :scope for omniauth-facebook ,but when I click login, I don't get any extra permission that I want to request from user. I seek over the internet and found out that I have to do like:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
// handle the response
}, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```

But in my case, I follow the client side and come out with this:

```
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

  // Init the SDK upon load
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'app_id', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//'+window.location.hostname+'/channel', // Path to your Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  oauth      :true, //enable Oauth 2.0
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
//
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback';
  }
}, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});  //i tried but its not working

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
        FB.api('/me', function(me){
          if (me.name) {
            document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
          }
        })
        document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
        document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
      }
    });

    // respond to clicks on the login and logout links
    document.getElementById('auth-loginlink').addEventListener('click', function(){
      FB.login();
    });


    document.getElementById('auth-logoutlink').addEventListener('click', function(){
      FB.logout();
    }); 
  }
```

If I use facebook social button and add the scope in html there, it works, but that's not what I want. Anyone here got tutorial or hints for me to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
jQuery ->
  $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>')

  $.ajax
    url: "#{window.location.protocol}//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
    dataType: 'script'
    cache: true


window.fbAsyncInit = ->
  FB.init(appId: '<%= ENV["FACEBOOK_KEY"] %>', cookie: true)

  $('#sign_in').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    FB.login (response) ->
      window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback' if response.authResponse
  , scope: "email, publish_stream"    

  $('#sign_out').click (e) ->
    FB.getLoginStatus (response) ->
      FB.logout() if response.authResponse
    true
```